# Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined) SANITY.IO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

> Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined)

I did my ImageBuilder configuration in another file and imported the urlFor function into my component. While I am able to map through/spread my values, I am not able to get the image url using the `urlFor()`

Running my queries in another file and importing a promise that I can handle with a `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(() => {
        const SLIDE = async () => {
            const slideItems = await SLIDES
            setSlide(...slideItems)
        }
        SLIDE()
    }, [])
```

I can access my data with the object properties. i.e: `{slide.slide_title}`

The thing is when I run the query from sanity studio, I get my values, and when I console.log too I get my values too BUT this `urlFor(slide.slide_image).url()` does not work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling `urlFor(slide.slide_image).url()`? Can you please show that part of the code?

Comment: What does `slide.slide_image` return? It will need to be a Sanity image record, an asset record, or the asset id as a string.